# Taylor Expansion of complex function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tz+t^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}P_n(z)t^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Expanding
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tz+t^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}P_n(z)t^n$$
when $z \in \mathbb C$

I am trying to prove some prove that $P_n(z)$ satisfying:

1. $$(n+1)P_{n+1}(z)-(2n+1)zP_n(z)+nP_{n-1}(z)=0$$
2. $$P_n(z)=P_{n+1}'(z)-2zP_n'(z)+P_{n-1}(z)$$
3. $$(2n+1)P_n(z)=P_{n+1}'(z)-P_{n-1}'(z)$$

The method seems obvious: find the derivative of the both sides. But the hard part is just the function itself:$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tz+t^2}}$$
It is hard to handle, so I doubt that if there is anything particular about this form of function.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, you could start writing $$1=\sqrt{1-2tz+t^2}~~\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}P_n(z)t^n$$ and now consider $$\sqrt {1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}-\frac{5 x^4}{128}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Replace $x$ by $(t^2-2tz)$ and use the binomial theorem.

If I did not make any mistake, the beginning of the sum should be looking as $$1+t z+t^2 \left(\frac{3 z^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+t^3 \left(\frac{5
   z^3}{2}-\frac{3 z}{2}\right)+\cdots$$